# Can I use Parameters<T> to lazily type my ...args param?

Tags: typescript, parameters

I want to run methods for an interface using another function (so I can give errors throw during execution some contextual information). I was hoping I could get Typescript to do the heavy lifting for me using the `Parameters` utility type... but I can't seems to get it to work.

Here's the reduced case:

```typescript
interface Store {
    read(key: string): string
    write(key: string, data: string): boolean
}

function run<T extends keyof Store>(store: Store, job: T, ...args: Parameters<Store[T]>) {
    return store[job](...args);
}
```

And the error:

```
(parameter) args: Parameters<Store[T]> 
Expected 2 arguments, but got 0 or more.
temp.ts(3, 11): An argument for 'key' was not provided.
```

Does anyone know how I might do this without having to write all the function signatures for `run` out by hand? I'm kinda new to typescript and must be missing something.

---

As an aside, vscode can correctly tell how these usages are wrong: [vscode doing magic?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CdXhw.png)

Answer (score 1):

TypeScript resolves the lookup in an unhelpful way. If you check the type of `store[job]` you get:

```
const func = store[job];

// Hover func here => const func: (key: string, data: string) => string | boolean;
return func(...args);
```

So it just merges all the function signatures, which messes up the call.

As you know that this should be correct, i would recommend telling TS to shut up about it and [check for an issue in the TypeScript repository](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues) and maybe file a new one if nothing fits. Maybe it is a bug that could be fixed, maybe it a limitation that will stay.

```
function run<T extends keyof Store>(store: Store, job: T, ...args: Parameters<Store[T]>)
    : ReturnType<Store[T]> {
    // @ts-expect-error
    return func(...args);
}
```